# domain "refused to connect" running django app on digitalocean droplet

Tags: networking, server, dns, nginx, connection

I want to deploy a site on a digitalocean droplet. So far, it works as expected when I hit the IP address 123.45.678.910, but when I go to my domain name, I see **"This site can't be reached, my-site.com refused to connect"** on Chrome. I am able to `ping mysite.com` and I see that it goes to the right IP address.

I connected my Namecheap domain to my droplet using [this tutorial](https://ron.sh/how-to-connect-a-namecheap-domain-with-digitalocean/). I've waited 24 hours which I think should be enough time for the domain name to propogate.

I don't see anything recent in the nginx error logs. When I check the status of nginx, gunicorn, and gunicorn.service on the droplet they all appear to be running.

Here's my `/etc/nginx/sites-avaliable/my-site` :

```
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name my-site.com 123.45.678.910;

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location /static/ {
        root /root/my-site/;
    }

    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/run/gunicorn.sock;
    }
}
```

I tried to install an SSL cert with this command:

`sudo certbot --nginx -d my-site.com -d www.my-site.com`

I don't think it worked, but I'm not sure if this could have something to do with it.

Let me know if there is any more information that you think I should include, I've never done this before so any information is helpful.

Thanks!

EDIT: I'm seeing this in the output of `systemctl status nginx`. It's just a warning (famous last words) but I'm wondering if it could be the causes as using the IP address works but the domain name doesn't.

```
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/nginx.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Wed 2023-03-22 00:40:42 UTC; 3min 1s ago
       Docs: man:nginx(8)
    Process: 185516 ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/nginx -t -q -g daemon on; master_process on; (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Process: 185527 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/nginx -g daemon on; master_process on; (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   Main PID: 185528 (nginx)
      Tasks: 2 (limit: 1131)
     Memory: 3.2M
     CGroup: /system.slice/nginx.service
             ├─185528 nginx: master process /usr/sbin/nginx -g daemon on; master_process on;
             └─185529 nginx: worker process

Mar 22 00:40:42 my-site systemd[1]: Starting A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server...
Mar 22 00:40:42 my-site nginx[185516]: nginx: [warn] conflicting server name "my-site.com" on 0.0.0.0:80, ignored
Mar 22 00:40:42 my-site nginx[185516]: nginx: [warn] conflicting server name "my-site.com" on [::]:80, ignored
Mar 22 00:40:42 my-site nginx[185527]: nginx: [warn] conflicting server name "my-site.com" on 0.0.0.0:80, ignored
Mar 22 00:40:42 my-site nginx[185527]: nginx: [warn] conflicting server name "my-site.com" on [::]:80, ignored
Mar 22 00:40:42 my-site systemd[1]: Started A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server.
```

Comment: Silly question, but is the configuration file also in `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled`? This is usually done with a symbolic link (using `ln -s`) for consistency. After making a symbolic link, nginx will need to be restarted in order to flush the cache and reload the enabled sites.

Comment: @matigo I created the symlink but had made some changes to my `sites-available` file afterwards, so I just recreated it. I still get the same issue unfortunately!

Comment: After making changes, nginx must be restarted (or reloaded). The configuration files are only read when the web engine starts up 

Comment: @matigo I have done `systemctl restart nginx` and also tried `nginx -t` (tests are successful). The issue persists

Comment: I found something that might be helpful coming out of `systemctl status nginx`, I will update above

Comment: @matigo updated

Answer (score 0):

This WAS related to the firewall.

First of all, I was getting weird errors when I initially tried running the `certbot` command and had to reinstall pip. I followed the below commands:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install python-certbot-nginx
sudo ufw allow ssh
sudo ufw enable
sudo ufw allow 'Nginx Full'
sudo ufw delete allow 'Nginx HTTP'
sudo ufw status
```

The status command shows that everything is allowed (for now). Now I add my SSL cert:

`sudo certbot --nginx -d my-site.com -d www.my-site.com`

It will prompt you on whether you want all sites directed to secure access.

After updating my firewall and adding my SSL cert, my-site.com is now live! :D